# Asp.net MVC addons

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have asp.net mvc application in which we have avoided using addons but now i would like to see which can really add value and use them, please suggest which addons are winning the race in each area

**IOC/DI**

- ninject
- structuredmap

**View Engine**

- Spark

**T4MVC**

Above are some that i tried little bit as we have some requirements which can be made easy with this.

Please suggest any addons which has made your life easier in mvc.

Comment: 1) You've only listed two addons in one of your areas. 2) Define winning?  Ninject and StructureMap are equally perfect for most apps.  Its only when you get down to esoteric features and your specific requirements when the differences become relevant.

Comment: Sounds more like something for the Community Wiki than a question to me, given that 'winning' as you put it is quite subjective, and nobody can have a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has an IOC/DI library called [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/).

For dead simple error logging and error log browsing, I like [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

You've got to have an ORM for database applications, such as Linq to Sql or [NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.com/)

[Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is an "Enterprise Job Scheduler"

[The Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/castle/projects.html) has a bunch of libraries and a complete framework that are worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

for me - T4MVC (or more specifiacally, T4 templates used against mvc v2). especially when used with subsonic. i've 'heavily' invested in customizing a whole raft of these with subsonic that literally 'builds' 90% of my plumbing and base functionality code. the fact that everything is standardised (and the fact that i can also build the tests in tandem) makes this one feature my - 'can't live without' - addon for mvc.

your mileage may vary...

jim

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing some of these. Care to share?

Answer (score 0):

I'm building a site now with MVC2, Ninject, NHibernate w/ FluentNHibernate (using Automapping), Spark and jQuery and it's probably the best/most fun experience I've had writing  a web application.

But I think it will end up being your personal preference.  Some people like SubSonic, some like NHibernate.  I don't think you can go wrong.